Unable to SSH into Rocky Linux 9 Virtual Machine from Windows Host despite SSH Configuration Changes
I'm encountering difficulties SSHing into my Rocky Linux 9 Virtual Machine hosted on VirtualBox from my Windows 11 host machine. Despite making changes to the SSH configuration, I still receive "Permission Denied" errors. Here's a breakdown of the issue and the steps I've taken:
Problem Description:
I'm using Rocky Linux 9 within VirtualBox on my Windows 11 host machine.
I am unable to log in as root using the username and password within the VirtualBox environment.
When attempting to SSH from the Windows host machine using the command ssh root@ip, I receive a Permission Denied error after entering the password.
I have modified the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file by changing the value of PasswordAuthentication to yes and ensured the line is active.
Following the configuration changes, I executed the command sudo systemctl restart sshd and also restarted the server, but the issue persists.
Steps Taken:
Modified /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Changed PasswordAuthentication to yes and ensured the line is active.
Executed sudo systemctl restart sshd.
Restarted the virtual machine.
Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to SSH into the Rocky Linux 9 VM from my Windows 11 host machine.
Additional Information:
The IP address used for SSH is correct.
There are no network connectivity issues between the host and the guest.
I've verified that SSH is running on the Rocky Linux 9 VM.
I have double-checked the password for the root user.
I'm seeking guidance on resolving this SSH permission issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Can you login as a regular user?

Did you also set PermitRootLogin in your sshd_config file?

@steeldriver, no, what will be the value?

AFAIK the default is ProhibitPassword which allows key-based but not password-based authentication - if you want to log in as root using a password (not recommended, for security reasons) it would need to be yes. See for example Why would a ssh password-based login fail?
